# Embedding Font from Fonts.com and Android Browser Version 2.3.6

Tags: android, webfonts

Got a curious issue with Fonts and the Android Browser Ver 2.3.6

Website: http://www.confektz.co.uk

When viewing on my Android Phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace, using Android Browser Ver 2.3.6), the only text that displays correctly is the copyright notice in the footer.

All other text is garbled?

All other browsers all text appears ok.

Can't figure this one out.

If anyone has got any ideas on how to fix this?

Many thanks,